# Order NULLs first in H2 SELECT query

Tags: sql, select, null, sql-order-by, h2

How to SELECT data ORDERED BY NULLs first in H2 DBMS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `NULLS FIRST`:

```
select *
from the_table
order by some_column NULLS FIRST;
```

`order by ... nulls first/last` is ANSI SQL and supported by H2

See the manual for details: http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#order